# Yii url rewrite strange behavior (.htaccess + urlmanager)

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, url-rewriting

I am hiding index.php and making the url friendly with the following code

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And in main config,

```
'urlManager'=>array(
               'urlFormat'=>'path',
                'showScriptName'=>false,
                'rules'=>array(

                ),
         ),
```

It works as expected, but the problem is it always redirects to the login page "site/login" when a non-existent url is entered. So, if the url is wrong/doesn't exist instead of showing a 404, it redirects to login page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check rights to access actionError for guests. You can also turn on LogLevel debug in apache to track rewrite rules. But this seems to be more security rules issue than rewrite...

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I don't know how it escaped me.I created an escape filter for sitecontroller and actionerror was being filtered for guests. Nothing to do with the url rewrite. Could you post as answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check rights to access actionError for guests. You can also turn on LogLevel debug in apache to track rewrite rules. But this seems to be more security rules issue than rewrite

Answer (score 1):

When using **Path** `urlFormat` You need to activate `useStrictParsing` to render the 404 pages for incorrect URL, modify your config like this

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'useStrictParsing'=>true,
    'rules'=>array(

    ),
),
```

see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlManager#useStrictParsing-detail for more details

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was however a stupid mistake on access filter on my part (see @emte's comment).

Comment: as long as it is solved :).. strictParsing also can cause similar problem , although it wont *always* redirect to site/login of course